# Physical memory size limit on a iPhone device - per application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Is there any limit on the physical memory size (file system) one can utilize in a iPhone application. My concern is what if someone keeps on writing some data files in the Documents folders and do not purge it. And the data can be of any size.

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague...can you be more specific?  All devices (mobile or otherwise) have limits.  Are you speaking about a single file or a collection of files?  Are you concerned that, perhaps, a log file will grow infinitely?

Comment: I don't know about reality, but in a perfect Apple such application won't be approved.

Comment: @TReddy: Yes, Its a log file growing infinitely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Max Disk Space an iPhone App Can Use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897034/max-disk-space-an-iphone-app-can-use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only hard storage limit is that of the total available space on the iOS device.

The scenario you have described is likely reality... there is a feature in the upcoming version of iOS that will assist in managing this issue, but it's still under NDA so cannot be discussed here. (yet)

EDIT: And in iOS 5, on your device you can now go to Settings -> Usage to get a list of all installed apps on your phone/pad/pod and see how much extra space they are consuming. :)

Comment: Isn't it lifted tomorrow or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASL or GTMLogger to manage your log files.

Some links that might be handy for you:

[Best Practices for Error Logging and/or reporting for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667994/best-practices-for-error-logging-and-or-reporting-for-iphone)

[objective-c logging best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480363/objective-c-logging-best-practices)